# Get value of object from array and match it to an id value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Based on the id of the link clicked the div's height and width has to change based on the respective value mentioned in the array

The id value of the clicked link is getting displayed properly but the dimension of the box is not correct.

Is the If statement wrong or the way dimension is written is wrong

```js
function myFunction(values) {
  
    
  var x = document.getElementById(values).id
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;

 var arr = [
  { id: 1, width: '300px', height: '400px'}, 
  { id: 2, width: '500px', height: '500px'}, 
  { id: 3, width: '100px', height: '100px'}];
  
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = i;
    if(x==arr[i].id)
      {
    
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = arr[i].height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = arr[i].width;
  }
 else{
       document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Error in entry";
     } 
  }
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>

<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
<div id="box" style="border:solid 1px red;">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The dimensions match the values you specified for each object.

Comment: The box resizes as it should in my browser.

Comment: `document.getElementById(values).id` makes no sense. Surely `values === id`?

Comment: @DeepikaRao, Works perfectly for me.

Comment: @SagarV you mean you are not getting the display - Error in entry

Comment: @DeepikaRao why do you need the else part? It will run everytime it doesnt match the id.

Comment: Alright. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if any id matched, else will run 2 times.

otherwise, it will run 3 times.
So the error message will be there anyway.

So, if you want to show the error message, use a `flag` and if id found, break the loop;

Then the `i` value hold the index matched.

Try this code.

```js
function myFunction(values) {
  
    
  var x = document.getElementById(values).id
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;

 var arr = [
  { id: 1, width: '300px', height: '400px'}, 
  { id: 2, width: '500px', height: '500px'}, 
  { id: 3, width: '100px', height: '100px'}];
  
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = i;
    if(x==arr[i].id){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
  }  
  if(flag==1){
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = arr[i].height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = arr[i].width;
  }
 else{
       document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Error in entry";
     } 
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>

<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
<div id="box" style="border:solid 1px red;">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. this is what was required. I need to break the loop if condition is met, since the if else is within the for loop. Got it. Thanks again

Comment: glad it helped. you can consider marking it as answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the is what you were looking for?

The else is removed and I use a flag instead

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    width: '300px',
    height: '400px'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    width: '500px',
    height: '500px'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px'
  }
];


function myFunction(x) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
  var found = false, box =  document.getElementById("box");
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (x == arr[i].id) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = i;
      found = true;
      box.style.height = arr[i].height;
      box.style.width = arr[i].width;
      // break; // if you only want to look for one
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    box.innerHTML = "Error in entry";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>
<hr/>
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
<div id="box" style="border:solid 1px red;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I works fine as i see, i think you are trying to achieve is this

```js
function myFunction(values) {

  var x = document.getElementById(values).id
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;

  var arr = [{
      id: 1,
      width: '300px',
      height: '400px'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      width: '500px',
      height: '500px'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px'
    }
  ];

  var item = arr.find(function(i) {
    return i.id == x;
  });
  if (item) {
    document.getElementById("box").style.height = item.height;
    document.getElementById("box").style.width = item.width;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "Error in entry";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="myFunction('1')">July 3, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="myFunction('2')">July 10, 2013</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="myFunction('3')">July 17, 2013</a>

<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
<div id="box" style="border:solid 1px red;">
</div>
```